# Asking the best method or way to <verb> something

Tags: grammar

In English we say things like:

> What is the best way to *<verb>* something?

I understand 方法{ほうほう} as a method and 方{かた} after verb stem. The sentence that caused me to contemplate was (in English):

> What is the best way to ask for directions in Japanese?

Or

> "What is the best way to say *weird/strange* in this sentence?"
>    <sub>(Sort of assumes the listener knows the English words *strange* or *weird*.)</sub>

My thoughts were something like:

> ”weird/strange” という[一番]{いちばん}いい[方法]{ほうほう}なんですか。

Comment: We have a question with answers explaining the difference between かた and ほうほう, which you might like to read: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6823/1478

Answer (score 3):

There's no question in this question! What are you asking here?

If you are asking the Japanese translation of "What is the best way to ask for directions in Japanese?", 日本語で道を聞く一番の言い回しは何でしょうね is my version.

Similarly for "What is the best way to say weird/strange in this sentence?", I would say この文にweird/strangeっていうニュアンスを入れたいんですけどどうしたらいいでしょうね or weird/strangeっていう感じを無難に入れるにはどうすればいいでしょうね.

「weird/strangeと言う一番いい方法はなんですか」 would do, but you can't omit 「は」 here.