# Use of 方に In this sentence

Tags: particles

> どうしても入り方にこだわりたいのか...

I'd like to know how 方に works here. I don't think it's read 入{はい}り方{がた}, 'time of setting', given the context I have. More likely it's 入り + 方に, since in the story the speaker seems be coerced into entering some kind of contest.

I found [an example on Tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/107532) of 方{ほう}に translated as 'made for':

> 彼{かれ}は戸口{とぐち}の方{ほう}に進{すす}んだ
>   'He made for the door'

Maybe that use of 方に could fit into the sentence in question...

Comment: Care to provide the rest of the context?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's  `入{い}り方{かた}`, which here means "way/means of entering [the contest]". And `こだわる` here is probably "insist on, make fuss about". So, I get something like:

"Do you really want to get me into that contest no matter what?"

Check a grammar book about the [`～方` suffix](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6823/).

Comment: Where do you get "me" from?  And we do not say 「コンテストに入る」, either.

Comment: From "the speaker seems be coerced into entering some kind of contest". I assumed he's saying this to whoever is forcing him to enter. But maybe I should have waited for more context...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, 「入り方」 is read 「はいりかた」 --「**か**た」, not 
「**が**た」.  It means "how to 入る".

Although OP has not provided enough context, I am going to jump the gun and post an answer.

「入る」 here looks like it is being used for its slang meaning of "to start a performance".  It is used rather heavily in show biz since many performers think the beginning part is important for the success of the rest of their performance.

「～～にこだわる」 means "to stick to one's way of doing ~~".

Thus, the sentence in question would mean:

"Do you absolutely have to (or "want to") stick to your own way of starting your performance?"