# Difference between 方法, 仕方 and simply 方?

Tags: word-choice

They all mean "way" or "method", but each have their own nuances. This [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6823/difference-between-%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B3-%E6%96%B9-and-%E9%81%8A%E3%81%B6-%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) is explaining the difference between 方法 and 方, so I guess we could focus on the difference of 仕方 with the other two. Are there any other words that could be similar and have a slight different meaning?

Comment: Can you give an example where you think 方 or 方法 could be replaced with 仕方?

Comment: Well this is the question, from a definition standpoint they are equivalent in english, what is the difference in Japanese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have read the link you provided I assume you are comfortable with adding 方 to the masu-stem of a verb to mean 'way of doing verb' e.g. 食べ方 (way of eating). The question is, what happens when you have a する verb? You might think something like 勉強しかた would be correct but, just like other uses of する, this one is irregular. The correct way to write it would be 勉強の仕方. So, quite simply, 仕方 is used with する verbs.

You could replace 仕方 with 方法 to get 勉強の方法 but this is just the formality difference discussed in your linked post. Replacing 仕方 with 方 would be ungrammatical.

仕方 also appears in set phrases like 仕方がない ("it can't be helped").

Comment: In other words, you say that 仕方 is the する equivalent of the 方 suffix of verbs, which would mean "way of doing" in a broad sense, meanwhile 方法 is more the methodical, didactic type of "way of doing", correct?

Comment: @Simon I think that summarises my ramblings, yes.